# How do you Parse this String in Lua "1 2 3 4"?

Tags: lua

I am brand new to Lua from a pure VB.Net background.  I have a large file of maplines that I need to iterate through.  The data is in the form of:

;XX.XXX  YY.YYY  Name
;
[Airways]
58.50 -12.44 58.21 -13.73

58.21 -13.73 57.89 -15.02

57.89 -15.02 57.54 -16.30

57.54 -16.30 57.17 -17.58

57.17 -17.58 56.76 -18.84

56.76 -18.84 56.33 -20.10

56.33 -20.10 55.87 -21.35

54.33 -25.02 53.77 -26.22

I have tried this but keep getting an error.

```
local mapLines = {}

local filePath = system.pathForFile( "data.ini", system.DocumentsDirectory )

local file = io.open( filePath, "r" )

if file then
local contents = file:read( "*a" )

--print( "Contents of " .. filePath )
--print( contents )

io.close( file )

local t = display.newText( "Contents of ", 5, 80, nil, 16 );
t:setTextColor( 255, 255, 136, 255 );
local t = display.newText( filePath, 5, 100, nil, 10 );
t:setTextColor( 255, 255, 136, 255 );

local ylast = 130
for line in io.lines(filePath) do  
    local t = display.newText( line, 15, ylast, nil, 14 );
    t:setTextColor( 255, 255, 255 );    
    ylast = ylast + 20

    n = tonumber(line);
    if n == nil then

        local f = {}
        s = "1 2 3 4"
        for k, v in string.gmatch(s, "(%w+) (%w+)") do
        f[k] = v
          end



local myLine = newLine(tonumber(f[1]), tonumber(f[2]), tonumber(f[3]), tonumber(f[4]))
        table.insert( mapLines, myLine )
    end
  end
end


-- Example of shape drawing func


local function newLine(x,y,x1,y1)

-- need initial segment to start
local Line = display.newLine( x, y, x1, y1 ) 

Line:setColor( 30, 155, 30, 100 )
Line.width = 3

return Line
end

Runtime:addEventListener( "enterFrame", mapLines )
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Dave

Comment: Please fix formatting. Please state the details about the error you get or produce a minimal example, which works in Lua console. Your code is clearly for some Lua-scriptable framework.

Comment: I've substantially reformatted the code. A key thing I did was replace all tabs with spaces, as tab characters are misunderstood by the markdown engine. I also condensed out most of the blank lines. Please feel free to put some back if I've been too hard on it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

answering the question in the topic:

```
local string_to_parse = '1 2 3 4'

for s in string_to_parse:gmatch('%d+') do
   print(s)
end
```

sample code on [codepad](http://codepad.org/YSuMiy7W)

Comment: thanks lhf, I've edited the answer using your tip. Still a bit new to patterns ;)